Python integer saved by reference instead of value in an iterable
I have a simple for loop with a count variable that gets saved into a dictionary as part of a string.
def chunk_page(page):
    pages = []
    chunks = chunk_string(page['content'], 500, 40)
    ints = []
    cnt = 0
    for chunk in chunks:
        ints.append(cnt)
        tmpPage = page
        if cnt == 1: chunk = chunk[0:chunk.rfind(' ')]
        else: chunk = chunk[chunk.find(' '): chunk.rfind(' ')]
        tmpPage['content'] = chunk
        if('_' in tmpPage['metadata']['id']):
            tmpPage['metadata']['id'] = str(page['metadata']['id'][0:-1] + str(int(cnt)))
        else:
            tmpPage['metadata']['id'] = str(page['metadata']['id'] + "_" + str(int(cnt)))
        pages.append(dict(tmpPage))
        cnt = cnt + 1
    return pages

In my mind, the id should just be iterated, however the at the end of the loop, the values are all set to the latest value
ie I get 3 pages with an id like 272975842_2.
I'm not sure how my referencing is wrong here, how do i explicitly copy cnt into this str value, why is it still cnt after being added to the string?

What's ints for?

The dictionaries you're putting in your list contain references to the same objects. See Deep copy of a dict in python

the int is just there becuase i had a copying issue with tmpPage previously, but dict(tmpPage) solved it, so I was hoping that int(cnt) would solve it, it is unnecessary

thank you khelwood, this has helped the issue

The issue is not with cnt, but with tmpPage. When you do tmpPage = page you're not creating a new copy of page, just a new reference to the same dictionary. When you're modifying tmpPage, you're modifying page as well.
To fix it, you need to create a copy of page before modifying it:
import copy
def chunk_page(page):
    pages = []
    chunks = chunk_string(page['content'], 500, 40)
    ints = []
    cnt = 0
    for chunk in chunks:
        ints.append(cnt)
        tmpPage = copy.deepcopy(page)
        # The rest of your code


Thank you! This solved the issue!
However I am unsure as to what is exactly going on:
its not like the pages are the same, the returned list returns different tmpPages, i actually had this problem earlier, but doing dict(tmpPage) solved this, the id field is the only one that is not different.
